# Load SWF files with tween effect - AS3.0 + Flash CS3

Tags: actionscript-3, flash-cs3

Load multile SWF files from XML data and upon NEXT and BACK button it should appear in Movieclip.. and it should have Tween effect..

I have created some code... in which i have loaded all the SWF on Stage.. and depending upon NEXT and Back button , i need to adjust next SWF file to show in movie clip.

plz help me

Thanks

Comment: This question is vague and pleading. Anyone interested in helping would need a lot more information, and hopefully some code, to get anywhere.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try XML slideshow component...